# Problems getting Auth:: user()

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm new to Laravel. I want to get an authorized user using the Auth::user () facade, in order to extract its ID, in the logout() method this is obtained and the authorized user is returned as an array with its data, but in the store() method Auth:: user () returns null. Tell me, please, what is the problem?

AuthController (here is logout()):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UserCreateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserLoginRequest;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Exception\AtextAfterCFWS;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\Uses;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function store(UserCreateRequest $request){
        $user               = new User();
        $user->login        = $request->get('login');
        $user->password     = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
        $user->email        = $request->get('email');
        $user->number_phone = $request->get('number_phone');
        $user->assignRole('user');

        if (!$user->save()) {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Регистрация не удалась']);
        }

        return response()->json(['message'=>$user->jsonSerialize()]);
    }

    public function login(UserLoginRequest $request){

        $user = User::query()->where('login', $request->get('login'))->first();
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)) {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Попытка входа не удалась'], 400);
        }

        $token = $user->createToken('api_token')->plainTextToken;
        $user->api_token = $token;
        $user->save();
        $user = Auth::login($user);

        return response()->json(['message'=>Auth::user()->api_token], 200);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        dd(Auth::user());
        $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы вышли из системы'], 200);
    }
```

AuthController (here is store()):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\ApplicationCreateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Application;
use App\Models\Status;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ApplicationController extends Controller
{
    public function showById($id) {
        return response()->json(Application::find($id), 200);
    }

    public function show() {
        return response()->json(Application::all(), 200);
    }

    public function store(ApplicationCreateRequest $request){
        dd(Auth::user());
        //$application                = new Application();
        //dd(Auth::user()->api_token);
        //$application->user_id       = Auth::id();
        //$application->status_id     = 1;
        //$application->description   = $request->get('description');
//
        //if (!$application->save()) {
        //    return response()->json(['message'=>'Заявка не отправлена'], 500);
        //}
//
        //return response()->json(['message'=>$application->jsonSerialize()]);
    }

    public function delete(Application $application) {
        if ($application->delete()) {
            return response()->json('Заявка удалёна', 200);
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Заявка не удалёна'], 500);
    }

//    public function updateStatus(Application $application)
//    {
//        if ($application->status_id)
//    }
}
```

api.php:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ReviewController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Requests\UserLoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {

});

Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('authStore', [AuthController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('authLogout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::get('application/{id}', [ApplicationController::class, 'showById']);
Route::get('application', [ApplicationController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('applicationStore', [ApplicationController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('applicationDelete/{application}', [ApplicationController::class, 'delete'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

//Route::post('userDelete/{user}', [AdminController::class, 'delete']);
Route::post('userStore', [AdminController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('user', [AdminController::class, 'show']);
Route::get('user/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'showById']);
Route::post('userDelete/{user}', [AdminController::class, 'delete'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');


Route::get('review', [ReviewController::class, 'showReview']);
Route::get('review/{id}', [ReviewController::class, 'showReviewById']);
Route::post('reviewStore', [ReviewController::class, 'store'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('reviewUpdate/{id}', [ReviewController::class, 'updateReview'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('reviewRatingUpdate/{id}', [ReviewController::class, 'updateReviewRating'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::get('reviewRating', [ReviewController::class, 'showReviewRating'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::get('reviewRating/{id}', [ReviewController::class, 'showReviewRatingById']);

Route::get('authUser', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
```

Comment: Make sure you are using `web` middleware. `store`  method should be grouped under `auth` middleware. show your route file for `Application` controller in question

Comment: On api `Auth::user()` will return null. you can try with add this middleware on route `middleware('auth:api');`

Comment: All added routes

Comment: for logout you are using `middleware('auth:sanctum');` try using it in the store route also

Comment: I'm already using it

Comment: Thank you all for your responsiveness! I solved the problem by running php artisan route: cache

Answer (score 0):

Define middleware in the constructer of your controller and it will do the trick here

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

Or  moved the route into Route::middleware it will work

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
Route::post('authStore', [AuthController::class, 'store']);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }
```

at the start
register method

```
   public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|between:2,100',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:100|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6',
            'mobile' => 'required|min:10',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
        }

        $user = User::create(array_merge(
            $validator->validated(),

            [
                'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
              
                
            ]
        ));

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User successfully registered',
            'user' => $user
        ], 201);
    }
```